# Implement Post ranking algorithm with Likes and Time difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm

How can I rank the posts with the likes and time difference(How old is the post) in ruby on rails. Is there any suitable algorithm for this task.

Here is the code for algorithm

```
@rank = 0.00
s = post.likers(User).count
order = Math.log10([s.abs, 1].max)
if s > 0
    sign = 1  
elsif s < 0 
    sign = -1
else
    sign = 0
end
td = (Time.now - post.created_at)
td2 = td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + ((1000000*(td.seconds)).to_f)/1000000
seconds = td2 - 1134028003
@rank = (sign * order + seconds / 45000).round(7)
post.update_attributes(popularity: @rank)
post.save!
```

Comment: Your question expects that everyone knows exactly what the Reddit post ranking algorithm does, which is not the case.  You should explain, in simple terms, what you want to do and then people can tell you whether or not the code is doing that.

Comment: Here is one (old) approach used by Hacker News: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=231209

Answer (score 1):

[How Reddit ranking algorithms work](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588). If posts can only be liked, that is, if number of likes is always positive number you can simplify that equation by removing `y`.

**UPDATE**

ruby implementation of linked algo

```
def hot(ups, downs, date)
  s = ups - downs
  order = Math::log([s.abs, 1].max, 10)
  sign = if s > 0 then 1 elsif s < 0 then -1 else 0 end
  seconds = date.to_f - 1134028003
  (sign * order + seconds / 45000).round(7)
end
```

Note that he doesn't use `Time.now` here. In this implementation the older the post, the smaller time difference (`seconds`) is, so it makes sense to treat it as a reward (to add it).

In your implementation, `seconds` is difference between now and post creation time, so you should treat it as a penalty, by either subtracting `seconds / 45000` or by calculating `td` as `post.created_at - Time.now`, it doesn't matter.

You don't need `td2`.

Also, if you want to use an implementation with `Time.now`, keep in mind that you would probably have to run a script once in a while to update all records in the database.

Comment: I have implemented reddit post ranking algorithm but in my case it seems to favor the older posts over most liked post also there is a huge difference between the popularity of older post and most liked post.

Comment: It Returns the number of seconds from the epoch to date as mentioned in the post on http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

Comment: ok, in python `td` is `deltatime` object, so he converts it in num of seconds there. in ruby `Time.now - date` will return their diff in seconds, so I don't think that step is necessary at all. other than that, think that `td` should be `post.created - Time.now`. you're adding `td` to `score`, with `Time.now - post.created` the older the post, the bigger the score is.